# How to solve nginx SSL error?

Tags: ssl, nginx, openssl

The fallowing steps are done but as you can see the fallowing error appears:

`openssl genrsa -out privkey.pem 2048`

`openssl req -new -x509 -key privkey.pem -out cacert.pem -days 1095`

```
Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:FR
State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:City: Roubaix
Locality Name (eg, city) []:NICE
Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]: Our team name
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:IT
Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []: mobileapp.ourdomain.com
Email Address []:My email
```

[image]

Comment: You are using a self-signed certificate, you need a valid cert to avoid chrome showing that error if you need a basic web server with valid certificates and only host static content check this [www](https://go-www.com)

Comment: ***`CN=mobileapp.ourdomain.com`*** is probably wrong. Hostnames always go in the *SAN*. If its present in the *CN*, then it must be present in the *SAN* too (you have to list it twice in this case). For more rules and reasons, see [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639) and [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/608639) You will also need to place the self-signed certificate in the appropriate trust store.

Comment: Hi @jww self-signed certificate is not allowed anymore.

Comment: @jww I think FQDN is correct as others said chrome is not supporting or trust to self-signed certificates this is not duplicated question.

Comment: @Parsaria - The hostname is probably OK. The first problem to be solved is the location of the name. OpenSSL only puts the hostname in the CN; it does not put the hostname in the SAN. As far as I know, all browsers except Android Browser support self-signed end-entity certificates. But before the trust issue is solved, the certificate needs to be well formed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A self-signed certificate is not trusted by browsers. You have to provide a real certificate which is signed by a Certificate Authority.

One great solution is [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). It's free, open and their certificates are trusted by almost all modern browsers.